# How to record screen Android device M OS

Tags: android, adb, screen, record, ddms

I use command

```
adb shell screenrecord/sdcard/misscall.mp4
```

To record my screen. But affter 20-25s, it stop record

I want to record a video has duaration about 3 minute

Anyone can help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a specific programming question, and more appropriately belongs on [Android Enthusiasts][http://android.stackexchange.com]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do "screenrecord -d 180 /sdcard/thenameyouput.mp4

Answer (score 1):

You can try **screenrecording directly through Android Studio**. When you plug in your device while Android Studio is open, the Android Monitor should appear for your device. On the left hand side of that panel, there is a **green play button** that you can click to screen record. As far as I know, you can start and stop the video on command as well as choose a place to save the file.